# pd.to_datetime does not convert object to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime-format

My current dataset is as follows:

[cleaned_df dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eItZw.png)

[Data type of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WD75.png)

To provide more details to my column headers, I renamed the headers as follows:
`cleaned_df.rename(columns={'month':'yyyy_mm','no_of_rainy_days':'no_of_rainy_days (days)', 'total_rainfall':'total_rainfall (mm)', 'mean_rh':'monthly_mean_humidity (%)', 'mean_sunshine_hrs':'mean_sunshine_hrs (hr)', 'cpi':'consumer_price_index (%)'})`

As seen in image 2, my month column is of an object data type and I would like to convert it to a datetime64[ns] format.

I tried the following code:
`cleaned_df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(cleaned_df['month']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')`
and it gives me the format of YYYY-MM as I wanted - image 1.

However, when i checked its information again, it still shows as an object. Additionally, the code throws a warning:
/var/folders/90/274n3kt55bl4fjg8t134196r0000gn/T/ipykernel_841/3350504036.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
cleaned_df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(cleaned_df['month']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

How do I properly code this according to best practice and to ensure the object gets converted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example Code**

```
s = pd.Series(['2020-01', '2020-02'])
```

`s`

```
0    2020-01
1    2020-02
dtype: object <-- chk dtype
```

**Step 1**

`pd.to_datetime` : convert datetime 64[ns]

```
pd.to_datetime(s)
```

result:

```
0   2020-01-01
1   2020-02-01
dtype: datetime64[ns] <-- chk dtype
```

**Step2**

`dt.strftime(format)`: convert datetime to string in given format

```
pd.to_datetime(s).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

result:

```
0    2020-01
1    2020-02
dtype: object <-- chk dtype
```

It's not that code you changed doesn't apply, it comes out as you changed.

Your code is converting str(object) to datetime and then back to str(object).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! If I would like to convert it to a date time format with YYYY-MM, is there a one line code that I can use or will I have to split it into 2 sections?

Comment: datetime cant be YYYY-MM format. You need to change datetime data type to object or period.